# Prove or disprove $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n \in B) = \mathbb{P}(X\in B)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, density-function

Let $\{X_n : n\geq 1\}$ and X be random variables om some probability space with probability density $f_n$ and $f$ respectively.

If $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere then for every $B \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ ( $\mathscr{B}$ for Borel set), prove or disprove $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n \in B) = \mathbb{P}(X \in B)$.

I appreciate it if you can tell me if the statement holds so that I can work on a proof or a counterexample.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is true. If you want an approach, I leave one in a comment.

Comment: I'm kinda tired of these ignorant downvotes. You would mind just looking at the question of OP before being unreasonable?

Comment: If you wanna downvote, just show yourself. If you have the courage to downvote then you must have the courage to stand for your action.

Comment: +1 to compensate the downvote.

Comment: Thank you @ParesseuxNguyen. I appreciate it. I will try to work on the proof.

Comment: and thank you for the upvote